# Как сделать обтекание объекта на другой объект?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, vcl

Есть форма. В форме по левому краю dbgrid, а по правому panel. Когда нажимаю на button, размер panel расширяется и форма становится длинной, появляется панель прокрутки в форме.

Как мне сделать чтобы при нажатии на button форма не расширялась, а длина панели облагалось на dbgrid?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что такое "обтекание объекта на другой объект", и "облагалось" ?

Comment: все  же объяснено, не поняли вопрос  Kromster? хочу чтобы поверх dbgrid было когда расширяться

Comment: Align используется? Если да, то скорее всего надо просто изменить свойство Left у панели, перед изменением её размера.

Comment: Align панели используется на right. Это как zed? объясните пожалуйста

Comment: Если у грида alClient, то изменение свойства Width у панели расширяет её в сторону грида и никаких полос прокрутки не появляется. Т.е. больше вообще ничего не надо менять. По крайней мере в текущей версии Delphi это так. Как оно работает в D7 я не знаю.

Comment: а нельзя как нибудь поверх dbgrid сделать?

Comment: Не очень понятно, что вы конкретно хотите сделать. Хотите спрятать грид, чтобы осталась только панель? И чтобы эта панель растянулась на всю форму?

Comment: Я действительно не понимаю ваш вопрос, и именно о непонятных частях в своем комментарии и попросил уточнить. Со мной согласились +2 человека. Постарайтесь пожалуйста формулировать мысли точнее.

Answer (score -1):

сделала как ZAD написал в комментариях помогло, при расширении ширины panel уменьшил и ширину dbgrid все получилось, тоже вариант)))

Comment: Пожалуста ставьте знаки препинания. Сейчас неясно что же вы конкретно сделали.